# How to get a variable of the original extension class

Tags: java, testing, junit5

I am the very beginner of Java, Spring and JUnit. I am trying to write code which uses `@ExtendWith` of JUnit 5. I want to use a variable (which is a random number) that is generated in my original extension class using @before and @after and judge whether it is an even or odd number at the test. However, the `getX` method returns 0 and the test class can never get the variable.

Here is my code. This is a test class. I would like to get variable "x" which is generated in `SampleExtension`.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.*;

@ExtendWith(SampleExtension.class)
public class Exercise {
    
    //@RegisterExtension
    SampleExtension sample = new SampleExtension();
    //@RepeatedTest(5)
    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
        int x = sample.getX();
        System.out.println(x);
        assumingThat((x % 2 == 0), () -> {
            System.out.println("this is an even number");
        });
    }
    
}
```

And this is an extension class.

```java
import java.util.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.*;

public class SampleExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {
    
    private int x;
    
    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext Context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterEach");
        System.out.println(this.x);
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext Context) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("beforeEach");
        this.x = (int)(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    }
    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext Context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterAll");
        this.x = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext Context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("beforeAll");
        this.x = 0;
    }
    
    int getX(){
        return this.x;
    }
}
```

The result.

```
Exercise > test() STANDARD_OUT
    beforeEach
    test
    0
    this is an even number
    afterEach
    4
```

Actually, `@RegisterExtension` (where I comment out in the test class) worked as I wished instead of `ExtendWith(someExtension.class)` and test class could get variable. But I would like to know how to do this using `@ExtendWith`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the way how Jupiter's extension lifecycle works, instant variables are just not suited to transport any kind of state from one execution of an extension callback to the next. To cite [Jupiter's user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-keeping-state):

> Usually, an extension is instantiated only once. So the question becomes relevant: How do you keep the state from one invocation of an extension to the next? The ExtensionContext API provides a Store exactly for this purpose.

So what you'll have to do is something similar to:

```java
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception    {
        System.out.println("beforeEach");
        int value = (int)(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        getStore(context).put("MYVALUE", value);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext Context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterEach");
        int value = (int) getStore(context).get("MYVALUE");
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    private Store getStore(ExtensionContext context) {
        return context.getStore(Namespace.create(getClass()));
    }
```

Mind that I haven't actually compiled the code so there may be bugs in it.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you. I'll try it and if it works, will be back soon and accept your answer as the best answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I tried your advice but it didn't work as I wished and this is because I didn't understand how to use Store methods properly. Then, can I ask one more question? How do I get the variable "value" whcich is generated in "extension class" and use it in "test class"? Your suggestion really helped but I would like to know more about it.

Comment: The extension must somehow provide the value for the test, e.g. through setting a variable by reflection or through a parameter resolver hook.